India 10yr Government security/bond yields
Which sites can provide historical data for India 10year government security which is monthly. Im assuming yield implies total return data (including dividends/interest) reinvested. Im a newbie so pls excuse if im missing any additional details

Does this answer your question? What data sources are available online?

couldnt find anything for India,
